# Line plot doesn't align with corresponding bars

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, linechart

I'm trying to make a bar chart with a line plot, but the line plot is starting from 2 instead or 1.

```py
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Arancium98/datasets/main/ventas_pizzas2.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)

VentaS = df.groupby('week')['total_price'].sum()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
VentaS.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax, title='Ventas por semana')
VentaS.plot(kind='line', color='tab:orange', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

The 'VentaS' start from the 1 and finish on 53, dtype: float64, so I'm not sure why the line chart doesn't start from the 1.

[image]

#### `df[['week', 'total_price']]`

```
       week  total_price
    0     1        14.00
    1     1        16.00
    2     1        18.50
    3     1        20.75
    4     1        16.00
...
48615    53        16.75
48616    53        17.95
48617    53        12.00
48618    53        20.25
48619    53        12.75
```

#### `VentaS`

```
week
1      9867.35
2     16002.80
3     15118.20
4     15655.80
5     16359.35
6     16183.95
7     16091.55
8     15354.90
9     15967.80
10    16577.95
11    15827.30
12    15719.75
13    15696.75
14    16961.40
15    16167.60
16    16093.00
17    16136.25
18    15231.75
19    16258.45
20    17143.45
21    15912.90
22    15306.80
23    16656.20
24    15893.65
25    15402.25
26    16228.05
27    17517.00
28    15898.45
29    16261.25
30    16362.15
31    14991.80
32    15620.95
33    16287.35
34    15686.60
35    14283.55
36    15548.75
37    16725.25
38    15985.85
39    11030.90
40    16821.55
41    13029.95
42    15488.70
43    14431.75
44    13264.70
45    16124.95
46    15458.05
47    14867.30
48    19762.15
49    16624.30
50    15677.25
51    15976.25
52    11433.85
53     7246.50
Name: total_price, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, pandas bar is plotted against 0 indexed x-ticks, and the label is a string. Line x-ticks correspond to the actual value. In this case, the first x-tick on the plot is 0, but the first value for the line is 1.

The problem is solved by adding :

```
VentaS = VentaS.reset_index()
```

So the desired code look like this:

```
VentaS = df.groupby('week')['total_price'].sum().reset_index()

ax = VentaS.plot(y='total_price', kind='bar', title='Ventas por semana', legend=False, figsize=(15, 5))
VentaS.plot(y='total_price', kind='line', color='tab:orange', ax=ax, legend=False)

# the labels must to set to correspond to the 'week' column
ax.set_xticks(VentaS.index, VentaS.week)
plt.show()
```

[image]